# How to replace a class element with another element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a link to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fkhan698/pen/gJbjKN) for a better understanding

So basically once the timer has run out and my Pause/Play buttons have disappeared I want the middleButtons class to appear. I have tried using a `for loop` for the `middleButtons` similar to what I did to make the Pause/Play buttons disappear. But nothing is happening. I don't have any error messages either.

Comment: Hey there - please include all relevant code directly in your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript logic was fine, the problem was with your HTML, you didn't closed some divs and you were hiding the div containing your middleButtons
I've updated your HTML [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGpoGd)

It was just a change in the middle div like this:

```
<div id="middle">
  <div id="counter"></div>
  <div class="pausePlay" style="display: none">
    <div class="row mr-3">
      <button id="pause">
        <i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
      </button>
      <button id="play" onclick="playAudio()">
         <i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size: 40px"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middleButtons" style="display: none">
    <div class="row mr-3">
      <button id="fiveMin" onclick="playAudio()">
        <h1>5 Min Break</h1>
      </button>
      <button id="endSess" onclick="playAudio()">
        <h1>End Session</h1>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```